# Calculating distance to nearest coastline from site locations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, distance, proximity

I want to calculate the distance to the nearest coastline from my site locations (point shapefile), and possibly the max distance as well. I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and I already have a shapefile of the coastline (lines), but I don't want to do it manually for each site using the "measuring" tool as I have hundreds of sites.

How else could I do it, perhaps using Euclidean Distance or Zonal stats?

Comment: The coastline is line, and my site coordinates are saved as a point shapefile - so vector. I am not really sure how to proceed. I have Advanced license so that's not an issue.

Comment: Please use the **edit** button to revise your question with those clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Near GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000) for that (Advanced license only).

It will add two fields to your point shapefile: one for distance to the nearest coastline feature and another for the coastline feature ObjectID.

[image]

Comment: For those without an ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced license (formerly ArcInfo license), this can be accomplished with the [Spatial Join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) tool. The `target_features` would be the points, the `join_features` would be the coastline, and the `match_option` would be `CLOSEST`.