# Calculating distance to nearest coastline with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, proximity

I am using ArcMap to calculate the distance from a list of coordinates to the nearest coastline. I downloaded the shapefile of coastlines from https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/ and converted the polygons into polylines. So, I have 2 shapeline files on ArcMap - one consists of the world coastline and another a list of coordinates. I also ensured that the linear unit of my input (i.e. list of coordinates) is in metres (but not other units like degrees). Basically, I followed the instructions in a previous thread, using the NEAR tool: [Calculating distance to nearest coastline from site locations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147479/calculating-distance-to-nearest-coastline-from-site-locations)

My results are shown here:[image: Neartable result]

However, the result is distorted as their distances all roughly equal to 569,736 metres with the same NEAR_FID. I cannot figure out what went wrong as I double checked every step.

Comment: Do both your shapefiles appear to be in the same coordinate system?  If so, are their coordinate values in the expected range for that coordinate system?  To check their extents look at their Properties.